# Clicking list of items then show to another list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show a list of items to another list by clicking it. The selected items are showing but only in a single line. I tried to add a break line but failed to do it.

I need to keep the items from list-select. It's like showing what I selected. The real scenario is selecting multiple products then show the selected product name

It needs to keep update the items from list-show if the customer remove the item from being selected.

```js
$(".list-select li").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
    $(".list-show li").html($(".selected span").text() + "<br />");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-select">
  <li> <span>item 1</span> </li>
  <li> <span>item 2</span> </li>
  <li> <span>item 3</span> </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-show">
  <li> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add (actually clone and then append new elements to another place) via `clone()` and `append()` jQuery methods. It's necessary for adding elements to the next list. For removing them from the second list (let's imagine, that it should work by clicking an item in the first list), you can use `li:contains(SPECIFIC_CONTENT_TO_MATCH)` to select the element, and then just `remove()` it:

```js
$(".list-select li").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
    $(".list-show").append($(this).clone());
  } else {
    $(`.list-show li:contains('${$(this).text()}')`).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select:
<ul class="list-select">
  <li> <span>item 1</span> </li>
  <li> <span>item 2</span> </li>
  <li> <span>item 3</span> </li>
</ul>

Show:
<ul class="list-show"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this simpler approach:

```js
$(".list-select li").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  
  $(".list-show").html($(".list-select li.selected").clone());
});
```

Comment: I can't run your code. {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: That's because that code is not standalone, it requires jQuery. Just replace your code with the code I provided, it should work.

Comment: Thanks! Your code is working but I need to keep the items from list-select. It's like showing what I selected. The real scenario is selecting multiple products then show the selected product name.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot the clone call. Now they are kept in their original place. The only problem I still see is that you lose the selection order, if you wanted that; you'll need some more lines of code to achieve that. I leave it on your hands.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing the html of the `show` list, you can append the clicked element instead.

For example:

```js
$( ".list-select li" ).on( "click", function() {
 $( ".list-show" ).append( this )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

list-select:
<ul class="list-select">
    <li> <span>item 1</span> </li>
    <li> <span>item 2</span> </li>
    <li> <span>item 3</span> </li>
</ul>

<div></div>

list-show:
<ul class="list-show">
</ul>
```

If you want to keep the original list, that can be done like this:

```js
$( ".list-select li" ).on( "click", function() {
   var clone = this.cloneNode(true);
 $( ".list-show" ).append( clone )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

list-select:
<ul class="list-select">
    <li> <span>item 1</span> </li>
    <li> <span>item 2</span> </li>
    <li> <span>item 3</span> </li>
</ul>

<div></div>

list-show:
<ul class="list-show">
</ul>
```

Comment: I need to keep the items from list-select. It's like showing what I selected. The real scenario is selecting multiple products then show the selected product name.

Comment: @lvlzero: can you update your question with details about both what you want, and what your use-case is? I don't know if the code in your question adequately represents your eventual use-case, so you *may* want to edit that as well.

Comment: @DavidThomas I added more details now. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @EthanRyan I'm sorry for not giving the real scenario. I edited the question. Thanks for helping!